# First return than free char value c

Tags: c, memory, return, free

In this function I need to return AND remove a char value (free the allocated memory).
What is wrong with this function?

```
char* pqueue_poll(PrioQueue *queue) {
        if (queue->root == NULL) {
            return "NULL";
        }

        else {
            char* name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
            q_elem *temp = queue->root;

            name = temp->name;      
            queue->root = queue->root->next;

            return name;

            free(temp);
            free(&temp->name);
        }
    }
```

I tryed first to free and than to return it but no result, I have some error with valgrind.
I have also a separate function (without deleting) that returns the value I want to return and remove here

Comment: How do you expect to free stuff after you have returned from the function?

Comment: first free and than return also do not work

Comment: You call `free(temp)` then immdiately use `temp` in the next line !  Although neither of those lines are reachable because you returned first.  Also you seem to intend to free some memory and also return pointer to that memory (obviously that will not work)

Comment: change the return logic to: `char *name = temp->name; free(temp); return name;`

Comment: this works but "18 allocs, 17 frees" because I have also to free temp->name and I cant free it because I have to return it first...

Comment: @Dmitry you cannot free memory and then use the freed memory

Comment: If you were to return the memory and then free it, the caller wouldn't be able to use the memory because you just freed it. How would that be any use?

Comment: Sorry my fault, I had to free the value in function that recive the returned value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a couple of major problems with you code

- `name = temp->name;` will just set `char *name` to point at the string you want to return. You need to do `memcpy` and then free the memory.
- `free` after `return` never will get executed

I guess what you want is

1. Allocate memory for return data (or use static array)
2. Copy the data from the queue
3. Free memory in the queue structure
4. Return the pointer (which one would have to `free` later if you didn't use `static` buffer for it)

Comment: Instead of allocating space, copying the memory and freeing the old, you could just return the old and not free...

Comment: @M.M yup, another way. I guess, I'd just copy it to some static array and don't care how it used later to avoid memory leaks.